# can not send $_POST (radio button) to another file

Tags: php, mysqli

i make a file that show up card type for user to select

```
<?php
include("connect.inc");
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or ("can't connect to server");
echo "<h2>Choose your card type </h2>";
$query="SELECT DISTINCT type FROM dragon";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can't execute query");
$counter=1;
echo "<form action='ShowCardType.php' method='POST'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo " <input type='radio' name='CardType' value='$type'";
    if($counter==1)
    {
        echo "checked='checked'";   
    }
    echo ">$type<br/>";
    $counter++;
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='select'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

the second is file is showing up cards that user selected.

```
<?php
include("connect.inc");
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or ("can't connect to server");
$type=$_POST['CardType'];
$query="SELECT * FROM dragon WHERE type='$type'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can't execute query");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo $type."<br/>";
    echo $DragonID."/";
    echo $type;
    echo $DragonName."<br/>";
    echo $Description;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='../dragon/{$picture}' border='0'> <img src='../dragon/{$picture}' border='0' width='300' height='300'/></a>";
}
?
```

>
However when the second file is run, it always output a notice that `Notice: Undefined index: CardType in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dragon-catalog\ShowCardType.php on line 4`
I think i did something wrong with the first file but i don't know where the error is .

Comment: I'm also having a hard time figuring out the "why". Try removing `value='$type'` for your radio input, since it's named and you're declaring it in your 2nd file `$type=$_POST['CardType'];` Other than that, I can't pinpoint the mistake.

Comment: Now it turns to a blank page.

Comment: Ok, well it was just a thought. Did you try Christopher's answer below?

Comment: i tried it too but it still output the same error.

Comment: Try this then `echo "checked='checked'>";` and `echo $type . "<br/>";`

Comment: Opp sorry it works when i removed value='$type' as you mentioned.

Comment: So, the problem has been solved?

Comment: I can make it an answer so we can close the question properly then.

Comment: It depends how it's being used. Does your book talk about the use of it in a DB, and in a loop?

Comment: yes it talks about the use of it in a DB, and in a loop.

Comment: Well, books can get it wrong sometimes, I've seen that happen before. I'm just glad that the matter was resolved. (Another Happy Ending) :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `value='$type'` for your radio input, since it's named,

and you're declaring it in your 2nd file `$type=$_POST['CardType'];`

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE `extract`!!!

Your extract is overwriting your variables.

Instead use `$row['type']` ... etc.